See followed by an infintive and gerund

Everyone has seen plants __________.

a. grow
b. to grow
c. growing
d. to growing
Which is the correct answer and why?

What do you think and why?

Both b and d are ungrammatical, but there's an interesting semantic distinction between a and c here.

Everyone has seen plants growing

This implies you see the actual process of a plant getting bigger before your eyes. This is unlikely to be true, as the process is too slow to see.

Everyone has seen plants grow

This is the correct answer, as it refers to having seen the outcome of the growth. If you see a plant on one day and then come back a few days later and it is bigger, you have seen it grow even if you have not witnessed the process directly.
But also note, confusingly, that this is fine:

Everyone has seen plants growing in a field

because the meaning here is not "the process of getting bigger" but simply "living", "existing" (because for a plant, being alive means growing).

I don’t think there’s any justification for this distinction.
